# Making an image act like a button

Tags: html, image, button

I'm working on a simple HTML page where I have this image that I want to act as a button.

Here is the code for my image:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 40px;"> 
    <img src="logg.png" width="114" height="38">
</div>
```

And basically I want to add this functionality into it:

```
<div>
    <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

The text on the button itself that says Submit is not needed as my image has the text it needs.

So anyway, is this possible? and if so, How? :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It sounds like you want an `image` button:

```
<input type="image" src="logg.png" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" id="saveForm" />
```

Alternatively, you can use CSS to make the existing `submit` button use your image as its background.

In any case, you ***don't*** want a separate `<img />` element on the page.

Comment: Why shouldn't there be a `<img>` element on the page inside the `<button>`?

Comment: `<button>` and `<input>` elements cannot contain other elements of any kind.

Comment: `<button type = "button">
     <img src = "">
    </button>`

Answer (score 13):

You could implement a JavaScript block which contains a function with your needs.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 40px;"> 
    <img src="logg.png" width="114" height="38" onclick="DoSomething();" />
</div>
```

Comment: Not the best option for forms.

Comment: I believe this would be an accessibility violation as, by default, an image is not focusable/tabbable and clickable with a keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an [image submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1):

```
<input type="image"  id="saveform" src="logg.png " alt="Submit Form" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got this to work:

First the css:

```css
    /* resets the button styling */
    button {
      all: unset;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Then, the html:

```
<button onclick="submit()">
  <img src="mycoolimage.png" />
</button>
```

This is cleaner IMO than the input submit approach and allows for ajax without the weird override default submit behavior.