# Like button (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, voting

Here's my like button:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Like">
    <input type="hidden" name="IP" value="<?php $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?>">
</form>
```

Here's the PHP:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $connection = mysqli_connect("like");
  $statement = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO Like (User, PageId) VALUES (?, ?)");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "si", $_POST["IP"], $_GET["id"]);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
  exit;
}
```

Can I use a custom image instead of the standard button?
And how do I display the amount of likes on the page?

I have two columns: IP and PageId.

Additionally, what is the "si" for? (didn't do that part myself).

Thanks!

Comment: `si` stands for `string` and `integer` respectively. You're telling the function that you're expecting your first bound variable to be a string and your second variable to be an integer.

Comment: Ah, thanks. When I googled it, I just got a random bunch of spanish.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, `si` stand for `string` and `integer`, you can find more details and the complete list at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

As for having a custom image, you can google "make an image act like a button", or visit this [Making an image act like a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131988/making-an-image-act-like-a-button)

To return the number of likes you would have to query the database for the count of rows where `PageId` = `$_GET["id"]`

a simple query can be like `select count(*) from Like where PageId = 10`