# Add text to image button

Tags: html

I am creating an image button and that works but I am unable to add text to it. I want the text to be from left to right in the button. I am adding the text inside the value but there is nothing shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
<input type="image" class="button submit" src="WhiteButton.svg" alt="submit" value="Add to favorites" />
```

Comment: Can it come on top of the image?

Comment: "I am creating an image button": then why are you using an `<input>` element??

Comment: Isn't an image button done using input? That is what I have learnt from tutorials

Comment: No, input is used for user input. `<button>` is used for a button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making an image act like a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131988/making-an-image-act-like-a-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
button.one { background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/150);
             font-weight: 900; color:white;
             width:200px; height:150px}
```

```html
<button class="one">SOME TEXT</button>
```